# When I try to debug test cases in visual studio 2019 debugging not working

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

When I try to debug testcases in visual studio 2019 debugging start and suddenly get stop and throwing some .dll files errors

Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in nunit.engine.core.dll

Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException' in nunit.engine.core.dll

Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException' in NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll

'testhost.net452.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 4): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'testhost.net452.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: domain-e0e63c75-Visa.CorpTools.Automation.VAM.dll): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'

The thread 0x1af8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll

The thread 0x114c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1c20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[13948] testhost.net452.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without more context of the problem it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I have added error message can you please look into this

Comment: Looks like you are doing something on an object that has been disposed already (`System.ObjectDisposedException`). Is this the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I am just trying to debug my testcase  it was working fine before but suddenly debug stop working

Comment: Working with disposed objects can cause errors randomly. It depends on when the garbage collector removes the object from memory. So yes, I think it is very well possible that it will work intermittently. I'll ask it again. Is this the complete stacktrace?

Comment: no its not complete stacktrace

Comment: i have added error message images as well

Comment: Hope the images will help you to understand .

Comment: At the very end I see 2 BadImageFormatException(s) but it all starts with the ObjectDisposedException. There lies your problem. Do you see any of your own code in the stacktrace somewhere. This is like looking for a needle in a haystack I'm afraid. Are you using GIT? If so, if you stash your changes. Does the code start working again?

Comment: I have only change the url in my app.config file apart from this i didn't made any changes and i don't have any idea about GIT.. what can i do for this can you elaborate because i am new in automation testing i don't have much more knowledge.

Comment: Try and cleanup the build environment. Close VS and find the .vs directory and delete it. Remove all `obj` and `bin` directories from your solution. Execute a 'Clean' (right click on solution => 'Clean solution'). And rebuild solution (right click on solution => 'Rebuild solution'). If that doesn't work I wouldn't know how you can fix this.

Comment: I didn't able to find .vs file can you please let me know from where i need to search.. in c drive either in my solution

Comment: Even i have checked in my solution too there is no any bin and obj folder is available

Comment: The .vs directory is hidden in Windows. You have to set the visibility for hidden folders to be able to find it. The same goes for the `bin` and `obj` directories. They default are hidden in Visual Studio. click the 'show all files' button at the top of the Solution explorer. This works on a per project base. So you will have to click that button for each project separately.

Comment: It didn't work for me .. i have shared complete stacktrace , do you have any other solution. what can I do for this

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of options. Are you working alone on this project. Is there no colleague that can help you?